# What are the major characteristics of Love Thy Neighbor?

Tags: christian-living

Does it include all of the following?

A. Sharing and caring (e.g., Matthew 25: 35,36)

B. Gentle and peaceful (e.g., Commandments 5 - 10; also Leviticus 19)

C. Lifetime, monogamous marriages between men and women. (e.g., Genesis 2:24);

Or is there more?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. I would recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Yes, it is all of those (in my own view) and yes, there is much, much more. But, as the question is closed. I am unable to post an answer. However, you may see my profile and see my details. Regards.